# Uppercase charfield

Tags: python, django

I have defined a field in Django

```
zip_code = models.CharField(_('Zip code'), max_length=19, blank=True, null=True)
```

In the moment, I need that each letter to be capitalized for that field. I use this field in `formlayout.py` file :

```
        Row(
            Column('city', css_class="s12 m5"),
            Column('state', css_class="s12 m5"),
            Column('zip_code', css_class="s12 m2"),
        ),
```

How could I capitalize `zip_code` without overriding the field itself? Could I create a `@property` method in which I will transform this field? What is the best place to put this method? `utils.py`? `views.py`? `models.py`?

For example, if originally `zip_code` is j3w 1w7, then I want it to become J3W 1W7

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a form or model form, the easiest thing to do is to add a [`clean_<fieldname>`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) method.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...

    def clean_zip_code(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['zip_code'].upper()
```

Comment: I need to put space between the third and the fourth character. Do you have an idea how to do that?

Comment: That's a separate question. What have you tried so far? Note that for [UK postcodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom) you want to put a space before the last three characters, not between the third and fourth characters. Consider `M1 1AE
` or `EC1A 1BB`.